# Сделать таблицу невидимой

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть элемент `table`:

```
<table class="textBlue">
```

И в него входит ряд элементов, которые нужно перестать отображать при определённых условиях. Как можно обратиться к этому элементу из кода *c#*? И как скрыть его? Насколько я помню, с помощью `display = block` можно как-то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, то скрыть нужно таблицу со всем её содержимым.

Что же, в голову пришли 2 варианта.

1. Поместить таблицу в теги `<div></div>` и скрывать всё, что есть в этих тегах

Пример:

```
<div ID="table_zone" runat="server">
   <table class="textBlue">
   ...
   </table> 
</div>
```

И тогда с серверной части скрыть div можно так:

```
table_zone.Style["display"] = "none";//Скрыть
table_zone.Style["display"] = "block";//Раскрыть
```

2. Скрывать непосредственно таблицу

Пример:

```
<table ID="Table1" runat="server" class="textBlue">
...
</table>
```

Серверная часть тогда должна работать с аттрибутами:

```
Table1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");//Скрыть
Table1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");//Раскрыть
```

На мой личный взгляд оптимальнее всего именно первый вариант. Он хорош ещё и тем, что помимо таблицы можно скрыть и другие элементы, находящиеся в границах этого div'а.

К тому же можно пойти дальше и сделать div'ы в div'ах и скрывать каждый по необходимости.

```
<div ID="div1" runat="server">
    <div ID="table_zone" runat="server">
        <table class="textBlue">
        ...
        </table> 
    </div>
    <div ID="div2" runat="server">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```